# Best way to store multiple dropdown list values in database?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

I'm working with a companies CRM database which contains clients that the company works with. Employees can create new client entries through the CRM and  when someone creates a new entry and checks multiple services that the client provides, the service codes are all stored in 1 field. Example below:

```
    clientid    CompanyName  Email    Tel    Services
    1           Randomname1  XXX@...  33333  ;14;294;448
    2           Randomname2  yyy@...  44444  ;448
    3           Randomname3  zzz@...  55555  ;58;448;14;65;24
```

So my questions is, what is the best way of storing the services column values? There are around 60 different services that you can choose from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic approach is:

Clients Table:

```
clientid    CompanyName  Email    Tel    
1           Randomname1  XXX@...  33333  
2           Randomname2  yyy@...  44444  
3           Randomname3  zzz@...  55555
```

Client_Services Table:

```
client_id   service_id
1           14
1           294
1           448
2           448
3           58
3           448
3           14
3           65
3           24
```